# Count categories with single query

Tags: sql, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to create a Spring data jpa request which returns the following result from REST API:

```
[ {category: “Laptop”, productsAvailable: 2}, {category: pc,
productsAvailable: 1}]
```

| id | category | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | laptop |  |
| 2 | pc |  |
| 3 | laptop |  |

How I can implement this with a single SQL request? I can make it with 2 SQL queries but I want to use a single one.

Comment: Where is the problem in doing that with a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JPA specification allows us to **customize results in an object-oriented.** You can use a JPQL constructor expression to set the result:

```java
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT new com.stackoverflow.TotalProductDTO(p.category, COUNT(p.category)) FROM Product AS p GROUP BY p.category")
    List<TotalProductDTO> countTotalProductsByCategory();
}
```

This binds the output of the `SELECT` statement to a `POJO`. The class specified needs to have a constructor that matches the projected attributes exactly:

```java
public class TotalProductDTO {

    private String category;
    private Long productsAvailable;

    public TotalProductDTO(String category, Long productsAvailable) {
        this.category = category;
        this.productsAvailable = productsAvailable;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Long getProductsAvailable() {
        return productsAvailable;
    }

    public void setProductsAvailable(Long productsAvailable) {
        this.productsAvailable = productsAvailable;
    }
}
```

You can see the Json output you want with a method like the one below.

```java
@RestController
public class ProductController {

    private final ProductRepository productRepository;

    public ProductController(ProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = {"/availableProducts"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> availableProducts() {
        List<TotalProductDTO> totalProducts = productRepository.countTotalProductsByCategory();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(totalProducts);
    }
}
```

As a result you will get this json:

```json
[
   {
      "category":"laptop",
      "productsAvailable":2
   },
   {
      "category":"pc",
      "productsAvailable":1
   }
]
```